# How to clone Greg Kroah-Hartman's stagingtree repository for the Linux kernel?

Tags: git, linux-kernel, git-clone

I am using git to try and clone Greg Kroah-Hartman's staging tree repository by using following command.

```
$ git clone -b staging-next git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/staging.git
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Cloning into 'staging'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.kernel.org:
git.kernel.org[0: 198.145.20.140]: errno=Connection refused
git.kernel.org[1: 199.204.44.194]: errno=Connection refused
git.kernel.org[2: 149.20.4.72]: errno=Connection refused
git.kernel.org[3: 2620:3:c000:a:0:1991:8:25]: errno=Network is unreachable
git.kernel.org[4: 2001:4f8:1:10:0:1991:8:25]: errno=Network is unreachable
```

What is the correct `git` command line to use?

Comment: Use https URL then: `https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/staging.git`

Comment: Looks like networking issue. Aren't you behind some firewall or something?

Comment: myaut I have used linux-next is it fine or I used for staging-next.

Comment: Krzysztof Adamski I have disabled firewall using ufw disable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As part of ensuring the information here is of a high quality, many first-time posts are reviewed by other members to see if they can be improved and clarified. In this case, I made the following changes: cleaned up the formatting, and separated the command from the error message; turned the title into an actual question; and added a specific - answerable - question in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git clone -b staging-next git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/staging.git

instead of this use this

git clone -b staging-next https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/staging.git

and disable the firewall or you can go for following link

https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/linux-next.html
and follow the instructions